# Prove that a linear mapping is not continuous by a counterexample

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Let consider $\mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$. Let $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ and $L$ a linear mapping such that $ \forall f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R}), L(f)=f(x_0)$. Prove that $L$ is not continuous when $\mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ is endowed with the $l_1$ norm.

I tried to consider a piecewise continuous function, but I can't manage to organize the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$
f_n(x) := 
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{x}{x_0} \right)^n & ,~ x<x_0 \\
1 &,~ x=x_0 \\
\left(\frac{x_0}{x} \right)^n &,~ x>x_0
\end{cases}.
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is not hard at all to check continuity of the $f_n$. We have (for $n>1$):
$$
\lVert f_n \rVert_{L^1([0, 1])} = \int_{0}^{x_0} \left(\frac{x}{x_0} \right)^n~\mathrm{d}x + \int_{x_0}^1 \left(\frac{x_0}{x} \right)^n~\mathrm{d}x = \frac{x_0}{n+1} + \frac{x_0 - x_0^n}{n-1} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
But $\lvert Lf_n \rvert = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
This means that $L$ is discontinuous.